# How do I put a personality test (or any series of questions with a purpose) in JSON-LD?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

One of our clients is a startup recruitment bureau for financial professionals. In order to 'lure' them into signing up, they want to tempt the visitor into taking an personality test. The result of that test is, ofcourse, one of nine personality types (more info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enneagram_of_Personality)).

I can't seem to find out where in the JSON-LD I'm supposed to show that the test concerns a personality test. I've got this so far (I've left out quite a bit of properties, they seem irrelevant):

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "potentialAction": 
        {
            "@type": "AskAction",
            "question": [ //foreach question in test
                {
                    "@type": "Question",
                    "headline": "", //question->title
                    "answerCount": "", //count($question->getAnswers)
                    "suggestedAnswer": [ //foreach question->getAnswers
                        {
                            "@type": "Answer",
                            "text": "", //answer->text
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "about": "enneagram",
            "result": "personality type"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, I've used `result` and `about` to kind of show Google that it's dealing with a personality test. However, the properties accept `Thing`s, so I could enter basically anything, but in the [full list of properties](http://schema.org/docs/full.html), there are no 'classes' for a personality test or anything like it, nor is there a result like a psychological type or personality type or character type.

Am I missing something, or is there no way to specify to Google that it's dealing with a personality test?

Comment: Why would there be schema markup for a personality test?   Even if there were, why would you want to use it?    Just put the test onto the page in HTML and don't worry about schema markup.

Comment: Following that logic, why is there a schema markup for a [ProgramMembership](http://schema.org/ProgramMembership), for a [CurrencyConversionService](http://schema.org/CurrencyConversionService), or a [SingleFamilyResidence](http://schema.org/SingleFamilyResidence)? People look for personality tests and other kinds of tests online, I'd expected there to be a markup that allows me to describe a general test at the least. There are markups to describe a car from colour to chassis to the amount of horsepower. I just wanna know if there's any kind of way to indicate a test people can take.

Comment: Schema makes your site more easily computer readable.   What service needs your data in a machine readable format?   Using microdata doesn't help search engine rankings, so it wouldn't usually help people find your site.

Comment: It's actually unclear if structured data helps rankings or not, so I won't go into a discussion about that. I do, however, admit that I misunderstood the idea behind, and the purpose of structured data. I thought that it had an established impact on rankings. I figured that Google would be able to better understand the page and adjust the rankings accordingly. I now see that it's basically to enrich the snippets Google might show for the search result. I stand corrected, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Stephen Ostermiller](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/14543/stephen-ostermiller) helped me realise in the comments on the question, there is no markup for any kind of test, and it's pretty logical that there is none.

It was my understanding that microdata/structured data was used to better understand the page, and its relevance to the search query. I assumed that would help rankings. It turns out, microdata is used mostly to [enrich search results with snippets](https://moz.com/learn/seo/schema-structured-data). It's still unclear if it does boost rankings, but it does explain why there's no markup for tests and things like that - it currently has no use to put that information in rich snippets.

Comment: I'm not sure why so many webmasters think that microdata will help rankings.   It seems to be a fairly persistent myth.   Right up there with "I need an XML sitemap" and "keywords don't matter anymore".